# The p^n torsion of a supersingular elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let k be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ and $E/k$ a supersingular elliptic curve.
It is well known that $E[p]$ is the unique autodual local group $I_{1,1}$ of Lie dimension $1$ such that $0 \to \alpha_p \to I_{1,1} \to \alpha_p \to 0$ is non split, and that $E[p^\infty]$ is isogenous to the $p$-divisible group $G_{1,1}$ (using standard notations from the Dieudonné-Manin classification).

But what can we say about the classification of $E[p^\infty]$ up to isomorphism? Or even what do we know about $E[p^2]$? These groups have a filtration with quotients equal to $\alpha_p$, but can we say more?

Comment: The isomorphism class of $E[p^{\infty}]$ also does not depend on $E$. This is because any two supersingular elliptic curve over $k$ are isogenous via an isogeny of degree coprime to $p$. They are isogenous via some isogeny because traces of Frobenius over a large enough finite field are equal, and any isogeny can be decomposed into a composition of a power of Frobenius and a separable one (the latter necessarily of degree prime to $p$). It remains to observe that any $E$ is separably isogenous to its Frobenius twist, e.g. by this answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/309357/39304

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you know the Dieudonné module associated to this $p$-divisible group?

Comment: It has a $W(k)$-basis $e_1,e_2$ with $\varphi(e_1)=pe_2,\varphi(e_2)=e_1$. The reason is that all $W(k)$ rk 2 Dieudonne modules $M$ over $W(k)$ such that $M[1/2]$ has slopes $1/2,1/2$ are isomorphic. To prove this, denote by $M_0$ the module I gave a basis for, and let $M$ be another module with $M_0[1/p]\simeq M[1/p]$. Let $f:M\to M_0$ be an isogeny of smallest degree. Then $f(M)$ is not contained in $pM_0$, so either $f$ is an isomorphism or $f(M/p)\subset M_0/p$ is the unique $1$-dimensional submodule.

Comment: Hence $f(M)$ is contained in $\langle e_1,pe_2\rangle$. But this module is isomorphic to $M_0$ via $e_1\mapsto e_2,pe_2\mapsto e_1$ so we could have decreased the degree of $f$. This by the way gives another proof of the claim that $E[p^{\infty}]$ is independent of $E$.

Comment: Thanks! You should post these comments as an answer!